# Find the determinants of the following matrices

Tags: matrices, determinant

> Let
>   $$\det\begin{bmatrix}
>    a& b & c   \\
>    d & e & f   \\
>    g & h & i  
> \end{bmatrix} = 5.$$
>   Find the determinants of the following:
>   $$1)\quad
> \begin{bmatrix}
>    a& b & c   \\
>    g & h & i   \\
>    d & e & f   
> \end{bmatrix},
> \quad
> 2)\quad
> \begin{bmatrix}
>    d& e & f   \\
>    g & h & i   \\
>    a & b & c   
> \end{bmatrix},\quad
> 3)\quad
> \begin{bmatrix}
>    a& b & b   \\
>    d & e & e   \\
>    g & h & h  
> \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know the basic properties of a determinant? how it's value changes after row/column exchanges?

Comment: I think you can find the determinant of a $3\times3$ matrix by your own. It's elementary algebra. Thence, you can solve the associate equations.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The determinant of the first matrix is 5, he's asking the determinant of all others.

Comment: @Nikunj  The first matrix is A where det(A) =5 using that information i have to find the determinant of other 3 matrices

Comment: Exactly the same question was asked 15 minutes ago by [this gentleman](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658177/if-deta-5-find-the-determinant-of-the-following). They must be doing the same homework assignment.

Comment: @bubba seems he has deleted the question

Comment: @DhanuRaja I know that, I want to know what you yourself have tried

Comment: @Nikunj well i went through the properties of determinant. But i dint find such property to tackle this questions

Comment: @DhanuRaja Seriously? Your book doesn't have row column exchange properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: you have probably learned that the value of a determinant changes in certain predictable ways when you swap two rows, permute the rows, etc.

For part #3, if you can't find any clever approach, just compute the determinant from the definition:
$$
\text{determinant} = a(eh-he) - b(dh - ge) + \ldots
$$

Comment: in Question 3, two columns are same so the determinant should be zero (i just learnt)

Comment: Correct. Very good. And you can confirm that it's zero by completing the computation that I started for you. Now look in the same section of your book for some other useful facts about determinants.